# Using Xamarin.Android layout preview with Dot42

Tags: dot42

Would it be possible to me to use Xamarin layout previewer inside a dot42 project? I'm about to switch my environment from Xamarin to Dot42, and the only thing that - I think - could be missing is a support for layout preview. Does by any chance someone made the test?

I know that Xamarin.Android requires business edition to be used in Visual Studio, so I fear there is no way with dot42 to see xml layouts.

Any possibility?

Comment: Currently, dot42 has no layout preview.

Comment: Well, that wasn't exactly my question, as I'm searching for a workaround to see interfaces, but thanks. :)